# NumPy: Dot product for many small matrices at once

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, dot-product

I have a long array of 3-by-3 matrices, e.g.,

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(25, 3, 3)
```

and for each of the small matrices, I would like to perform an outer product `dot(a, a.T)`. The list comprehension

```
import numpy as np

B = np.array([
    np.dot(a, a.T) for a in A
    ])
```

works, but doesn't perform well. A possible improvement could be to do just *one* big `dot` product, but I'm having troubles here setting up `A` correctly for it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the list of transposed matrices as `A.swapaxes(1, 2)`, and the list of products you want as `A @ A.swapaxes(1, 2)`.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(25, 3, 3)

B = np.array([
    np.dot(a, a.T) for a in A
    ])

C = A @ A.swapaxes(1, 2)

(B==C).all()     # => True
```

The [`@` operator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) is just syntactic sugar for `np.matmul`, about which the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) says that "*if either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.*"

Answer (score 1):

Looking closely at the code and trying to get a bigger picture reveals some information there. The first axis needs alignment between `A` and its transposed version as we are iterating through the first axis for both these versions in the code. Then, there is reduction along the third axis in both `A` and its transposed version. Now, to maintain the alignment and perform such a dot product reduction, there's one good vectorized option in [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). Thus, to solve our case, the implementation would look like this -

```
B = np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ijl',A,A)
```